# Exceptions when rendering PullToRefresh in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I use the [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library in my activity.

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    ...
</com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView>
```

The android project uses target SDK of 19. I launch the app and it can run correctly on my phone (Nexus 5, Android 5.0), but it cannot render in Eclipse (choosing API 19), reporting exceptions:

```
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.internal.LoadingLayout.<init>(LoadingLayout.java:83)
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.internal.RotateLoadingLayout.<init>(RotateLoadingLayout.java:42)
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase$AnimationStyle.createLoadingLayout(PullToRefreshBase.java:1328)
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.createLoadingLayout(PullToRefreshBase.java:587)
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.init(PullToRefreshBase.java:1108)
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.<init>(PullToRefreshBase.java:113)
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView.<init>(PullToRefreshScrollView.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

I met some related errors for 3rd party views where just the view itself was not rendered. Now in Eclipse the whole layout file is not rendered. This makes me not easy to adjust UI quickly. Any reason making this error happen?

Answer (score 0):

This issue disappeared. I guess it was because I went through the layout xml file and make every element correct...